# Why is building with Make 3.8.1 different to Make 4.1?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am building an Embedded ARM project using `gcc` with C++:

```
11:01:29 ○⨠ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288]
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is  NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and make:

```
17:11:17 ○⨠ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

I was building a recent piece of code and it just *wasn't* working for me at all - the code built and deployed fine but the functionality just wasn't there. Tt made no sense as the code looked entirely fine.

A colleague reviewed it with me and we could find no problem with the code so for a laugh, we decided to get him to build and deploy it.

It worked fine!

So inspecting our versions, he was running `make 4.1`. I upgraded to this and hey presto, it worked fine.

```
11:06:15 ○⨠ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

We played some more with  `3.81` and deduced that optimisation may have been the problem.

But both instances were passing `-Os` to `gcc`.

So, my question is this - why would `Make` have an influence on the compiler here?!

Comment: `make` itself really has very, very little idea about `-Os`, GCC and optimization flags. Makefiles are rules to call external programs with specific arguments, and `make` executes those rules. The knowledge about `-Os` is in one of those rules.

Comment: You should compare the commands executed when you run the Makefile in Make 3.8.1 compared with when you run it in Make 4.1. All Make does is run commands as specified by the Makefile. Also, how did you deduce that optimisation could be the problem?

Comment: You mean `3.81`, not `3.8.1`.

Comment: @MSalters I know - thats why it confused me so much! Surely Make should just be passing the same arguments?

Comment: @Archimaredes We deduced it by taking a variable out of a decision path and it worked fine, as if it was optimising this variable out. That said, maybe thats a big leap? I am going to examine the executed commands more closely as I could not immediately noticed much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu make behaves a little differently between version 3.8.2 and 4.1 when 'Makefiles remade' occurs.
For example, execute following commads:

```
----- commands ----
rm ./sub.mk ./add_rule ; make -f test.mk HOSTCC=GCC

----- test.mk -----
$(info ===== test.mk(lv $(MAKELEVEL)) ==== )
$(info origin=$(origin HOSTCC))
HOSTCC = cc
$(info HOSTCC=$(HOSTCC))
$(info ------------------ )

.PHONY: all sub sub2

all:
    @echo "... build $@ ..."
    touch ./add_rule 
    @echo "*** using HOSTCC=$(HOSTCC) at all: ***"
    $(MAKE) -f ./test.mk sub
    @echo "*** using HOSTCC=$(HOSTCC) at all: ***"

sub:
    @echo "... build $@ ..."
    @echo "*** using HOSTCC=$(HOSTCC) at sub: ***"

-include sub.mk
ifneq ($(wildcard ./add_rule),)
sub.mk:
    @echo "... build $@ ..."
    echo "\$$$ (info --- $@(included) ---)" > $@
endif
----- end of test.mk -----
```

Using Ver 3.8.2 Gnu Make, Last few lines of console output is:

```
....
===== test.mk(lv 1) ==== 
origin=environment
HOSTCC=cc
------------------ 
--- sub.mk(included) ---
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/make-test'
... build sub ...
*** using HOSTCC=cc at sub: ***
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/make-test'
*** using HOSTCC=GCC at all: ***
```

Using ver 4.1, 'cc' does not shows up, but only GCC is there.

The point is:

In ver 3.8.2 Gnu make, variable 'HOSTCC' is not overridden in sub:recipe,
    even if it was specified in the command line.

( I noticed this phenomenon when building u-boot. 
  For more infomation about 'Makefile remade', 
  see make manual '3.5 How Makefiles Are Remade'.)

This difference seems to come from ver 3.8.2 gnu make's main.c(line 2091).

In ver 4.1 code, putenv() is not there.

```
/* Reset makeflags in case they were changed.  */
{
  const char *pv = define_makeflags (1, 1);
  char *p = alloca (sizeof ("MAKEFLAGS=") + strlen (pv) + 1);
  sprintf (p, "MAKEFLAGS=%s", pv);
  putenv (p); //<<=== the different point.
}
```

Comment: Sorry,
the console output of version 3.81 and 3.82 differ,
but version 3.81 and 4.1 are same.